How to calculate the inverse of formal series of tensors?
I am working trough this book. In definition 2.4. the space of formal series of tensors is introduced. It is defined as (for simplicity, think of $E$ as $\mathbb{R}^d$)
$$
T((E)) = \{\mathbf{a} = (a_0, a_1, \dots) | \forall n \geq 0, a_n \in E^{\otimes n}\}.
$$
For two elements $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in T((E))$ addition and multiplication are defined by
$$
\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} = (a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, \dots)
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} = (c_0, c_1, \dots)
$$
is for $n \geq 0$ given by
$$
c_n = \sum_{k=0}^na_k \otimes b_{n-k}.
$$
Now it is claimed that for $\mathbf{a} \in T((E))$ with $a_0 \neq 0$, the inverse of $\mathbf{a}$ is given by
$$
\mathbf{a}^{-1} = \frac1{a_0}\sum_{n \geq 0} \left(\mathbf{1} - \frac{\mathbf{a}}{a_0}\right)^n.
$$
Question: Why does this formula hold?
I got so far as to show that one can calculate the components of $\mathbf{b}:= \mathbf{a}^{-1}$ recursively:
$$
b_0 = 1/a_0 \quad \text{and} \quad b_n = -\frac1{a_0} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-k} \otimes b_k, \quad n \geq 1
$$
However showing that the representation for $\mathbf{a}^{-1}$ seems not too easy. If have tried some basic algebraic rearrangements but it got me nothing.
Has anyone a hint on how to show that $\mathbf{a}^{-1}$ is given by the above. Any reference would also be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
Edit: Thanks @Qiaochu Yuan! I get it now:
Define $b = \frac1{a_0} \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac a{a_0}\right)^n$. Then
$$
b (1 - \frac a{a_0}) = ... = b - \frac1{a_0} \implies b - \frac{ba}{a_0} = b - \frac1{a_0}
$$
and hence by rearrangement
$$
ba = 1.
$$
The case $ab = 1$ is similar.

It's just the sum of a geometric series and the proof is the same, multiply by $1 - \frac{a}{a_0}$. The same thing holds for formal power series (which corresponds to using symmetric tensors); are you familiar with that?

Thanks for the reply! I am not familiar with that. Multiplying both sides by $1-\frac a{a_0}$ and some rearrangement yields me $a^{-1} - \frac1{a_0} = a^{-1} - \frac1{a_0}$, which is true. However, I am not yet seeing how to derive the formula itself.

This is a proof that if you multiply the RHS by $a$ you get $1$. That's the definition of an inverse!

Thanks! Now I got it.
